Tie and Beam notes simultaneously in MuseScore 3
I have beam and tie notes as:

In my Score I got:

In the nex:

I got:

Is it possible to fix the tie using beam simultaneously?
How to do it in MuseScore 3?

You’ve posted it a lot of basic questions about using Musescore. Maybe you should read some introductory documentation?

Those aren’t ties, those are slurs

The horizontal lines that connect note stems, marked in blue in this image,

are beams. The curved line between the noteheads, marked in red, is a slur. Technically, when a slur mark is applied to two notes of the same pitch, it's a "tie."*
Slurs/ties and beams are different topics and you can handle them separately. To apply slurs across notes in MuseScore 3, you can click the first note, hold down Ctrl(/Cmd), and click the last note, or use other methods as covered in this page of the handbook. You might want to start by simply deleting the enormous multi-measure slurs that you've created.
MuseScore connects notes with beams when they're part of the same beat. If you want to break the beam between two notes, you can use the "beam properties palette," as described in this page. In your final image, you have this palette open; just select one of the notes for which you want to break the beam, and click the image that shows a note with a "flag" instead of a beam, the third one.
In the future, when you have a question about how to do something in MuseScore, start with a quick look in this documentation. (But make sure you're looking at the documentation for your version of the software!)
* (These are the terms in common use in modern English. In past centuries it's sometimes gotten complicated, like when a 17th century printer advertised that he'd gotten the technology to print "the new ty'd notes," but he meant beams.)

Ties and slurs are different things.  It makes no sense to beam two notes together and then also tie them, but you can put a slur between two different notes.
Although they look much the same, MuseScore distinguishes between the two, so you need to select the right one.

The OP's language should make it clear that they don't know how ties differ from slurs. Yes, they could look it up (as they could look up how to break beams and edit sluts), but this answer could be improved with a little explanation.
